# Could not set proper JBOSS_HOME directory in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jboss, wildfly

I'm just starting with Jenkins. I'm trying to set JBoss Management Builder (unless I do not need this plugin to control deployment on WildFly?) and Jenkins do not want to accept my JBOSS_HOME dir.
My home dir is:

```
/home/opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/
```

I have also tried:

```
/home/opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/
/home/opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/
/home/opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/
/home/opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

All of this tries have ended with an error: 
"It's not look like correct JBoss home directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's unlikely that the JBoss Management Builder plugin will work with Wildfly.

Its latest release is from 2011 as written on the [plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JBoss+Management+Plugin). Plus the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jboss-plugin/blob/6495ad31a9c8fefaddd79c7f58ee3675e5b09ebf/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/jboss/JBossBuilder.java#L189) where the error is coming from is looking for two folders explicitly in your JBOSS_HOME: "bin" and "server". And "server" is just not there in Wildfly.

I think you have to find other ways to interact with Wildfly.

Comment: Okey, that's make sense. Do you recommend any option?

Comment: You would want to start/stop Wildfly in your build, or just deploy on a running instance?

Comment: Let's say I would prefer deploy on a running instance

Comment: Well, I would try to use the same mechanism as used locally. If there is a maven target, or shell script that deploys, I would invoke that from Jenkins.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse to deploy everything. Can I somehow export my IDE settings and import to Jenkins?

Comment: I'm unsure, sorry.

Comment: Okay, Thank's for help!